# How do I obtain the foreign equivalent of homeowner's insurance when buying a vacation home in another country?

Tags: retirement, insurance, investing, home-ownership

I am considering purchasing a property in another country as a vacation home. I'll continue to live in the US (nation of citizenship), but may consider using the foreign home as a retirement locale, too, in several years.

What type of insurance do I need to purchase on the foreign property? Can I add it to my US policy, or do I need a country-based carrier?

If it matters, the home would be in the Caribbean (haven't picked the exact country yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I add it to my US policy, or do I need a country-based carrier?

Adding it to your US policy is highly unlikely. I recently
had occasion to rent an apartment in a **different state
in the US**, and my insurance agent in my home state could
neither add this to my home-owner's policy nor write a
renter's policy in the other state. I had to get an agent 
licensed in the other state to write a renter's policy.
This was with State Farm, by the way. Maybe other insurance
companies march to the beat of a different drummer.

For a policy on property in a *different* country entirely,
I doubt the average insurance agent would have a clue as
to what the minimum requirements for a policy are.